# Why can't I display the criteria pane in SSMS 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Where is it? How do I get to it?

I see a toolbar with what appears to be the icon for the criteria pane but it's greyed out.

I see the criteria pane inside the query builder but that's not what I want. I want the modeless criteria pane (not inside the modal query builder).

Answer (score 1):

- Click DB name
- Click Views
- right click -> select New View
- Add desired tables
- click Close

This is the only method I've been able to find that replicates the functionality in 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Hulo,
find a workaround for this. Right click on your table/view, then choose Edit Top n Rows.
Voila, the criteria pane shown up

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.